# Selecting SVG icons to click(); with Protractor

Tags: javascript, svg, protractor

> begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false
>
> language: lang-html

```
<fa-icon _ngcontent-c15="" class="check-box-font unchecked ng-fa-icon ng-star-inserted" ng-reflect-icon-prop="[object Object]"><svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fal" data-icon="square" class="svg-inline--fa fa-square fa-w-14" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512"><path fill="currentColor" d="M400 32H48C21.5 32 0 53.5 0 80v352c0 26.5 21.5 48 48 48h352c26.5 0 48-21.5 48-48V80c0-26.5-21.5-48-48-48zm16 400c0 8.8-7.2 16-16 16H48c-8.8 0-16-7.2-16-16V80c0-8.8 7.2-16 16-16h352c8.8 0 16 7.2 16 16v352z"></path></svg></fa-icon>

<svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fal" data-icon="square" class="svg-inline--fa fa-square fa-w-14" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512"><path fill="currentColor" d="M400 32H48C21.5 32 0 53.5 0 80v352c0 26.5 21.5 48 48 48h352c26.5 0 48-21.5 48-48V80c0-26.5-21.5-48-48-48zm16 400c0 8.8-7.2 16-16 16H48c-8.8 0-16-7.2-16-16V80c0-8.8 7.2-16 16-16h352c8.8 0 16 7.2 16 16v352z"></path></svg>
```

I'm writing some tests and having some issues when selecting SVG icons, as a checkbox.
I've tried with XPath, and with CSS Selector.
The code line is this one,

I tried to use the "Copy Selector" option from the console to grab the correct path, but with no success.
I'm using vars to click on the element,

```
var animalsInterest = element(by.xpath("//svg[@class='svg-inline--fa fa-square fa-w-14']"));
await animalsInterest.click();
```

Comment: Does it just not click the check box or does it produce some error?

Comment: It says this Failed: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression  because of the following error:
    SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '' is not a valid XPath expression.

Comment: I've tried to just copy the whole path and add to the CSS selector... but it did not work.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to create xpath for tag "fa-icon" instead of "svg", it means try to click element with tag "fa-icon" either by using xpath or by tagName or by Classname